# Logical Error in C++ Hexadecimal Converter Code

Tags: linux, error-handling, g++, gedit

I've been working on this Hexadecimal Converter and there seems to be a logical error somewhere in the program. I've run it on Ubuntu using the g++ tool and every time I run t program, it gives me a massive heap of garbage values. I can't figure out the source of the garbage values and neither can I find the source of the logical error. I'm a newbie at programming, so please help me figure out my mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    int bin[20],finhex[10],num,bc=0,i,j,k,l=0,r=10,n=1,binset=0,m=0;
    int hex[16]= {0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111};
    char hexalph='A';
    cout<<"\nEnter your Number: ";
    cin>>num;
    while(num>0)
    {
        bin[bc]=num%2; 
        num=num/2;        
        bc++;
    }       
    if(bc%4!=0)
    bc++;
    for(j=0;j<bc/4;j++)
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
             binset=binset+(bin[m]*pow(10,i));
             m++;
        }
        for(k=0;k<16;k++)
        {
             if(hex[k]==binset)
             {
                 if(k<=9)
                     finhex[l]=k;
                 else 
                     while(n>0)
                     {    
                         if(k==r)
                         {
                             finhex[l]=hexalph;
                             break;
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             hexalph++;
                             r++;
                         }
                     }    
                 l++;
                 r=10;
                 binset=0;
                 hexalph='A';
                 break;
             }
        }
        while(l>=0)
        {
            cout<<"\n"<<finhex[l];
            l--;
        }   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user64322 Try helping me out here ?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> int hex[16]= {0000,0001,0010,0011,0100,0101,0110,0111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111};
> ```

Allow me to translate those values into decimal for you:

```
int hex[16] = {0, 1, 8, 9, 64, 65, 72, 73, 1000, 1001, 1010, 1011, 1100, 1101, 1110, 1111};
```

If you want them to be considered binary literals then you need to either specify them as such or put them in some other form that the compiler understands:

```
int hex[16] = {0b0000, 0b0001, 0b0010, 0b0011, 0b0100, 0b0101, 0b0110, 0b0111, 0b1000, 0b1001, 0b1010, 0b1011, 0b1100, 0b1101, 0b1110, 0b1111};

int hex[16] = {0x0, 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0xa, 0xb, 0xc, 0xd, 0xe, 0xf};
```

Answer (score 0):

While Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams rightly hinted at the fact that some of your initializers of `hex` are (due to the prefix `0`) *octal constants*, he overlooked that you chose the unusual, but possible way of representing binary literals as *decimal constants* with only the digits 0 and 1. Thus, you only have to remove the prefix `0` from all constants greater than 7:

```
    int hex[16] = {0000,0001,10,11,100,101,110,111,1000,1001,1010,1011,1100,1101,1110,1111};
```

Then, you stored the characters `'A'` etc. in `int finhex[]` and did output them with `cout<<"\n"<<finhex[l]` - but this way not `A` is printed, but rather its character code value, e. g. in ASCII `65`. In order to really output the character `A` etc., we could change the `finhex` array element type to `char`:

```
    char bin[20],finhex[10]; int num,bc=0,i,j,k,l=0,r=10,n=1,binset=0,m=0;
```

- but consequently we also have to store the digits 0 to 9 as their character code values:

```
                 if (k<=9)
                     finhex[l]='0'+k;
```

Furthermore, with the lines

```
    if(bc%4!=0)
    bc++;
```

you rightly pondered on the need to have a multiple of 4 bits for the conversion, but you overlooked that more than one bit could be missing, and also that the additional elements of `bin[]` are uninitialized, so change to:

```
    while (bc%4!=0) bin[bc++] = 0;
```

Besides, you omitted block braces around the (appropriately indented) two inner `for` loops; since C++ is not Python, the indentation has no significance and without surrounding braces only the first of the indented `for` loops is nested into the outer `for` loop.

The final `while` loop should be outdented and go outside the big `for` loop. There's also an indexing error in it, as the `finhex` array is indexed with an `l` which is by one to high; you could change this to:

```
    while (l--) cout<<finhex[l];
    cout<<"\n";
```